# laravel display image in array in blade.php

Tags: laravel

I have an array name $slideshow of multi images, I want to display all images in the blade. my code

```
@if(count($slideshow) > 0)
    @foreach ($slideshow as $image)   
        <div class='carousel-item'>
            <img src="{{ url('/images/slideshow/'.$image) }}" width='1100' height='500'>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

[image: $slideshow]

Comment: okay, so what is the problem

Comment: image not display

Comment: Where do you store images?

Comment: in public folder

Comment: OOOps!  .  i forget <div class='carousel-item {{$x == 0 ? 'active': ''}}'>

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
 {{ asset('/images/slideshow/'.$image) }}
```

hope it will works :)